# C# Using Tor with GeckoFX Control

Tags: c#, proxy, tor, geckofx

How do I get a GeckoFX control based browser to use Tor as a proxy?

I have set the GeckoPreferences for:
    network.proxy.type to 1
    network.proxy.socks to 127.0.0.1
    network.proxy.socks_port to 9150 and the
            socks_version to 5

What else do I need to do, as this is not torifying my connections?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Tor default proxy port is 8118. use this port it will work...

```
127.0.0.1:8118
```